# Error #1602 mySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I am making a row in my table `order_detail` in mySQL database called `orderid`. I want to put a primary key constraint in it but it always shows an error #1602. Other details are as follows: int(11), NOT auto-increment. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Complete error message, complete table structure, complete command you issued, please.

Comment: #1602 duplicate error.

Comment: A primary key identifies one row exactly. If you have more than 1 row with the same value in this column, your primary can't work on that column. Either you get rid of your duplicate data, or you choose as much columns as needed to identify a row as primary key, or you create another column which serves as primary key, such as an auto_increment column.

Comment: You can find those rows with duplicates with `SELECT your_column, COUNT(your_column) as cnt FROM your_table GROUP BY your_column HAVING cnt > 1`